# how to populate cells in a UItableview with switfyJson from an alamofire post request

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a Tableviewcontroller embedded in a Viewcontroller. And i would like to populate this 3 cells with data from my alamofire post request. whats the easiest way to get that done? i can see my alamofire post request printed in the debug area. so far i came till now.

[image]
the viewcontroller looks like this.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewScore: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getScores()
        tableViewScore.delegate = self
        tableViewScore.dataSource = self
    }

}

public func getScores() {

    let URL_SCORES = "http://localhost/projecttitle/v1/scores.php"

    let username = "username@projecttitle.com"
        
        //creating parameters for the post request for now.
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "username":username
        ]
        
        //Sending http post request
        AF.request(URL_SCORES, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)
                
                switch response.result {
                    case .success (let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    
                    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["scores"] {
                        debugPrint (key) //key
                        debugPrint (subJson) //value
                            
                        debugPrint (subJson["date"]) //value
                        debugPrint (subJson["coursename"]) //value
                        debugPrint (subJson["score"]) //value

                    }
                        case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
       return count 
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellScores
        
        // populate the cells with date, coursename and score

        return cell
    }
}
extension UIViewController : UITableViewDelegate{
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
}
```

the UITableViewCell looks like this.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCellScores: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Model named "MyModel" at the outside of your view controller :

```
struct MyModel {
    let date: String?
    let coursename: String?
    let score: String?
}
```

And at your view controller define a variable:

```
var myModel = [MyModel]()
```

At your `getScores()` func `fill your model` :

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["scores"] {
    debugPrint (key) //key
    debugPrint (subJson) //value
                            
    debugPrint (subJson["date"]) //value
    debugPrint (subJson["coursename"]) //value
    debugPrint (subJson["score"]) //value

    self.myModel.append(date: subJson["date"], coursename: subJson["coursename"], score: subJson["score"])
}

tableViewScore.reloadData() //reload your tableview end of the for loop
```

Return `self.myModel.count` at your `numberOfRowsInSection` func

At `cellForRowAt` :

```
cell.dateLabel.text = self.myModel[indexPath.row].date
```

Comment: in the row `self.myModel.append...` i got the following error "Cannot find 'self' in scope" and in the row with tableViewScore.reloadData() i got the error "Cannot find 'tableViewScore' in scope"

Comment: Write your tableviews name at tableViewScore.reloadData(), also remove self from self.myModel.append

Comment: then i get the error "Cannot find 'myModel' in scope" and tableViewScore is the name of my tableview

Comment: where is the myModel defined?

Comment: i made a new file called myModel. 
`import foundation
struct MyModel {
    let teedate: String?
    let coursename: String?
    let golfclubname: String?
}`

Comment: the var myModel = [MyModel]() is inside the viewcontroller.

Comment: Is your target selected in the target field in the right part of the file?

Comment: i m not sure, how to i do that? i can see a Target Membership Window on the right side. there is the main project called 'tabletestproject' checked. 'tabletestprojectTests' and 'tabletestprojectsUItests' are unchecked. is that what u mean?

Comment: i tried something different now. i put the whole getscore function inside the override func viewDidLoad() ... now the `self.tableViewScores.reloadData()` is giving me no error anymore. also the `myModel` seems to be working but i got a different error now. **"no exact matches in call to instance method 'append'**

Comment: Can you share your view controller ?

Comment: i found the solution: instead of  `self.myModel.append(date: subJson["date"],...)` i found out i should use `self.myModel.append(MyModel(date: subJson["date"],...)`

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: one more tricky question, is it possible to sort the subJson Array before i pass it to the tableview? so i get oldest date first.

Comment: you can "reverse" func for your array

Comment: how does that works? can you give me an example? now the dates are all over the place because i didnt add the scores in a time related manner. means e.g. the oldest score is not the first data entry.

Comment: the easiest way is to update the msSQL query and sort the date there. but is that the best way?

Comment: I can't say anything without see your data.

Comment: i have made sample data. it looks like this: `tabletestproject.MyModel(date: "2013-04-06", coursename: “Example Course 22”, score: "75”), tabletestproject.MyModel(date: "2013-03-23", coursename: “Example “Course 4, score: “89”), tabletestproject.MyModel(date: "2013-03-09", coursename: “Example Course 12”, score: “50”)...]`

Comment: Try this : newArray = yourArray.sorted(by: {$0. date?.compare($1. date ?? "") == .orderedAscending})

Comment: how can i check in an IF or CASE statement which way the dates are sorted? because then i can make only one button for desc and asc sorting. ;) that means with one click i can sort it from oldest to newest and when i click again its sorted from newest to oldest.

Comment: change orderedAscending to orderedDescending in button click

Comment: I think you can do this yourself just think a little bit and focus :)

Comment: well, i will hopefully find out. ;)

Comment: `@IBAction func sortDate(_ sender: Any) {
        let scoreSort = myScore

        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if !(button.isSelected) {
                
                self.myScore = scoreSort.sorted { $0.tdate < $1.date }
                button.isSelected = true
            } else {

                self.myScore = scoreSort.sorted { $0.date > $1.date }
                button.isSelected = false
            }
            tableViewScores.reloadData()
        }
      }`

Comment: thanks again, i found out how. and it works :)))

Comment: Well done! Happy coding :)